# How to fetch unique records from mysql db

Tags: database, mysql

Example:

```
Rno name   Status
1   C       0
2   D       0
1   C       1
```

Now I just want fetch `2 D 0`.
Because c status get updated so i want to skip `1 C 0/1`.

Comment: use select distinct.

Comment: distinct return two records .

Comment: i just want single , because 2nd rows status 0 and not get updated

Comment: can you put your actual data in table form?

Comment: example i given above just consider as table